# HQL query for SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

What will be the HQL(JPA) query for the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM account 
GROUP BY companyname 
ORDER BY balance DESC 
LIMIT 10 ;
```

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like:

```
select account from Account account
   group by account.companyname
   order by account.balance desc
```

LIMIT is not supported in HQL, but you can use Query.setMaxResults() for this purpose. For example:

```
Query q = session.createQuery(query);
 q.setFirstResult(start);
 q.setMaxResults(10);
```